# Suspend Recurly Account Billing

Tags: recurly

Using the Recurly API, I am in need of being able to suspend an account when it enters past due and then unsuspend the account after payment. For this purpose, I define suspend as the account being active but not being billed for an undetermined period of time (until the event of payment). Recurly has a pause account feature. However, according to documentation, the account must not be past due. It also appears that this feature is time based instead of event based (ie the account is paused for a period of time instead of paused until payment).

For business background, the purpose of this request is to allow us to disable product features when an account is past due and then to re-enable product features after payment. When product features are disabled, I do not want to continue billing the customer. That would be a bad customer experience and result in having to issue credits.

Comment: I'm confused. If you bill them successfully, aren't they no longer past-due and would have access to those features again?

Comment: HI Ceejayoz. I am concerned about the point in time when they reach past due after a card has expired (or has not been provided at all). I want to avoid a situation in which invoices pile up on this customer by pausing all new invoices until the account has a good card that is billed for the past due balance. I also want to be able to identify this as a suspended state in order to suspend features for this customer until payment is made.

Comment: https://docs.recurly.com/docs/dunning-management#section-end-of-dunning-cycle "By default, dunning settings will automatically fail an invoice at the end of the dunning cycle if the invoice has not been paid. A failed invoice is Recurly's way of writing it off as bad debt, removing the owed balance from the customer's account." You'd then start a *new* subscription if the user opted to fix their payment settings.

Comment: Thanks Ceejayoz. I hadn't considered using dunning events. I'm currently researching Recurly for use as our billing tool and this was very helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! I haven't used it personally but have heard good things.